# ApplicationTestCase deprecated in API level 24

Tags: android, testing, android-testing

I created a default empty project on **Android Studio 2.1.2** with **API 24**. In the sample project, Google offers a depreciated class **[ApplicationTestCase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ApplicationTestCase.html)**:

> **This class was deprecated in API level 24.** Use ActivityTestRule
>   instead. New tests should be written using the Android Testing Support
>   Library.

**Sample:**

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

/**
 * <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html">Testing Fundamentals</a>
 */
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }
}
```

**My Question:** Why Android Test Case is now deprecated? How to replace ApplicationTestCase by ActivityTestRule?

---

**EDIT:**

I try with **[Expresso](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/downloads/index.html)**, but on **API 24** (`compileSdkVersion 24`) I have this error:

```
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'. Resolved versions for app (24.0.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:design'. Resolved versions for app (24.0.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (24.0.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7'. Resolved versions for app (24.0.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

When I try to add this lib in my build.gradle:

```
// Android JUnit Runner
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
// JUnit4 Rules
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
// Espresso core
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
// Espresso-contrib for DatePicker, RecyclerView, Drawer actions, Accessibility checks, CountingIdlingResource
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
// Espresso-web for WebView support
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'
// Espresso-idling-resource for synchronization with background jobs
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2'
```

> **My conclusion** is that for the moment neither **Android Test Case** nor **Expresso** works on **Android API 24**. Is this right?

---

**EDIT: 2016-08-05**

I fix previous error on **Expresso** like that:

```
def espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
def testRunnerVersion = '0.5'
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:${testRunnerVersion}"
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:${espressoVersion}"
configurations.androidTestCompile.dependencies.each { androidTestCompileDependency ->
    androidTestCompileDependency.exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Comment: googling "android espresso"

Comment: @HanbumBak I can't find a tutorial on Api 24

Comment: Regarding the dependency conflict error see: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181587/android-version-24-0-0-and-espresso-2-0-gradle-exception/38182270#38182270)

Answer (score 25):

The new **androidTest** example that the beta version of Android Studio 2.2 generates, look like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        assertEquals("org.mypackage", appContext.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

Just like the deprecation warning suggests, the new instrumentation tests  should use `InstrumentationRegistry` instead of extending from `AndroidTestCase`. Run them with `AndroidJUnit4`.

The relevant `dependencies` section in `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

Comment: Ok, but how do you replace `ApplicationTestCase`? It handles app setup and teardown between each test case.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Simply add a methods to your test case and annotate them with `@Before` and `@After` from JUnit, and perform your setup/teardown actions there.

Comment: I know that, my question was more targeted towards: what's the contents of those methods to **properly** create a new `Application` instance each time without leaking, conflicting and having the instance created in that test available through `context.getApplicationContext()` where needed inside the app?

Comment: If I am understanding it correctly, your Application class needs to handle that resource leaks regardless whether it is called from the Test class or not. Please see my answer below on how to use it instead of ApplicationTestCase.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the API documentation the API has been deprecated and instead use of the InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext() will in turn call onCreate method of your Application class.

The **getTargetContext** will call the **ApplicationStartupService** class defined in Android Manifest as below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       <application
           android:name=".service.ApplicationStartupService"

 public class ApplicationStartupService extends Application
 {

       /**
         * Method initializes the application configuration
       */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(){

          super.onCreate();

          this.initResources()
       }

      private void initResource(){
          //do your application init work here.
      }
}

Test Class

  @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)      
  public class ApplicationStartupServiceTest {

  @Test
  public void testResourcesAreInitializedd() throws Exception {
   //do your assertions here.
  }
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ApplicationTestCase

Answer (score 0):

With what can I replace

```
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }
}
```