# With Android api level 25 it is showing InstrumentationTestCase is deprecated , what is alternative for this?

Tags: android, ui-automation

Was trying to automate an android app by `UI Automator`, but when I extends `InstrumentationTestCase`, i found it is deprecated with my api level 25 . So how I can solve this problem any alternative class, please provide a example .

Comment: InstrumentationTestCase class was deprecated in API level 24. --https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308041/applicationtestcase-deprecated-in-api-level-24

Answer (score 1):

As per the doc `InstrumentationTestCase` was deprecated in Api 24

> This class was **deprecated in API level 24**. Use [InstrumentationRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html)
>   instead. New tests should be written using the [Android Testing Support
>   Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html).

You can follow [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html) tutorial for a working example.

Comment: Thank you .But how to use InstrumentationRegistry ? I tried as InstrumentationTestCase , it does not work ,an example would be better ,as i am new to this.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the tutorial link you can go through it.